# celery django + rabbitmq = dst bug?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm using celery (3.1) with amqp and kombu 3.0, together with RabbitMQ (3.4) to run asynchronous tasks for a Django backend.

Tonight I just encountered a strange situation due to dst (Daylight Saving Time), while in Central European Time, our servers went from UTC+2 to UTC+1. Meaning, it was 2 AM and then at 2:59 AM, instead of being 3AM, it was 2AM. I am wondering if this is a bug or if there might be something wrong in the configuration.

The strange thing is that I could see the queue growing up in the "first 2-3AM hours range", like if it wasn't getting consumed and the same queue being slowly acknowledge in the "second 2-3 AM hours range". But not like if at the second 2AM occurrence, it would try to ack all messages, but just regularly, at the same rythm there where stacked the first hour.

To make it simple, it looked like the messages needed one hour to be acknowledge, if there was some shift there. Any clue if this is a problem in the config or a bug ?

Thank in advance, Matt

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I think this is a bug in the celery.
Use UTC time for eta.